How to ensure there are sequential records in a nosql collection?
I've got a nosql database (Azure CosmosDB) with a collection that contains, in addition to other properties, records in this format.
{
    "id": "0574100324396001",
    "StoreId": 574,
    "TransactionSequenceNumber": 3960,
    "UnitSession": {
        "User": "Tom Smith"
        "StoreId": 574,
        "TillNumber": 1
    }
}

The records may get created in any order however I want to ensure that for a given StoreId and TillNumber, that the TransactionSequenceNumber are sequential and that there are no gaps e.g. for StoreId 574, TillNumber 1, there are TransactionSequenceNumbers 3960, 3958, 3959, 3961.
How could I go about doing this?

Cosmos DB doesn't have a sequential identifier. The only way you could do that is with your own application-scoped sequence-number-generation service (which is outside the scope of Cosmos DB, and will have its own challenges around concurrency, failed writes using generated sequence numbers, retries, etc). Alternatively, you can store a creation timestamp when you write your new documents as well, which would help you in your ordering (you cannot rely on the built-in _ts since that gets changed every time a document is updated)
